# When method signature is written inside print statement what is the output?

Tags: java

Ok now this is so confusing. I used to remember when method signature is written inside print statement it used to print only the return value of that method that it doesn't print the method itself as it is, it is only the return value gets printed. And that we cannot write a method inside print statement where the method does not return any value.

But now I see it completely different I am sure when the above was not correct it used to give an error. But now when I write the method inside print statement not only the return value but also values printed inside the methods get printed... How did this happen?

Comment: please show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected. Here's an example:

```
private String hello() {
    System.out.println("hello");
    return "world";
}

System.out.println(hello());
```

So what happens when executing this line? You're asking the code to print the expression `hello()`, of type String. So it first evaluates the expression by executing `hello()`, and then prints the result of the evaluation to `System.out`. So `hello()` is first executed.

The first thing `hello()` does is to print `"hello"` to `System.out`. So that's what happens. Then `hello()` returns `"world"`, and this returned value is printed to `System.out`. So the end result is

```
hello
world
```

being printed.

It's not magic, and what a method does doesn't change whether it's called "inside a print statement" or not. If a method is executed and writes to System.out, then it writes to System.out, whatever the way it's called.